# PHP sessions in two application

Tags: php, session

I've got question to you. I have got two project in PHP that uses captcha, and write it to session. My question is, if I fire first application, that saves captcha to `$_SESSION['code']` and then I start second application where I saves captcha to same variable, then the first value will be overwritten by second, or PHP will create two independent sessions?

Comment: Are these two applications on the same server?

Comment: yes, there are connecting to PHP scripts from diferent webistes, but connection is to same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, each application will override the session variables on the same server.

To avoid this, you can either namespace your sessions or use the `session_name` function.

You can namespace manually, by setting `$_SESSION['app1']['code']` and `$_SESSION['app2']['code']` or by using a session abstraction library like the one from Symfony or Zend Framework.

Using `session_name` in each application could look like this:

```
//Other init stuff here
define('APPLICATION_ID', "MY_UNIQUE_ID_1");
session_name(APPLICATION_ID);
session_start();
```

You'll have to change the unique id in some configuration file for each application. I put a `define` here to show that it doesn't come out of thin air.

Comment: can you show me some example how to use session_name in my current situation?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to [set a cookie path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) (before `session_start()`).

Answer (score 0):

In my experieance, If both of your application is on same virtual directory then it will be overwriten. 
So if you do not want to overwrite each other use different session variable.

Regards